# Users upload images to website and then is displayed in gallary

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, gallery

So I have an admin panel built, I am wanting to be able to upload images, change the name of the image file to a number ID which is generated by how many rows there are already in the database. Then have them displayed in a gallery for visitors. I have looked around the internet for a few days now, trying different scripts, mixing and matching, but nothing seems to work. This is PHP btw. I beleive the issue is the move_uploaded_file() function. If anyone could think of a better way or find an error in my code, that would be fantastic. The website is for a client so it would be even more appreciated for promptly replies. Thanks guys

```
require_once("../php/connect.php");

function GetImageExtension($imagetype){
    if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
    switch($imagetype){
        case 'image/png': return '.png';
        default: return false;
    }
}

if (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])){
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $imgtype = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
    $ext = GetImageExtension($imgtype);

    $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gal";
    $count = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);

    $imagename = $count + 0;
    $newfilename = "$imagename" . ".png";

    //Debug
    echo "hello <br>";
    echo "$newfilename";
    //End Debug

    $folder = "/uploads/";
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "$folder" . $_FILES['image']['$newfilename'])){
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO `nocas_19164639_admin`.`gal` (`id`, `name`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, '$newfilename', '1')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    }else{
        exit("Error while uploading file...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can i ask why you want to rename the file to a number relating to the row it's on?
Your making a simple task very complex. 
You shouldn't store the images in your database, you should upload them to a directory within your site and store the corresponding name in the db.

I don't understand the whole reason for changing the name to a number though, it's just making a mess of everything.

you should just do something like this.

create a directory path in your config file..

```
defined("UPLOAD_DIRECTORY") ? null : define("UPLOAD_DIRECTORY", __DIR__ . DS . "uploads");
```

I have created a function for mysqli query just so i dont have to type it out all the time.

```
function query($sql) {

global $connection;

return mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
```

I then have a confirm query which checks for an error on the query.

```
function confirm($result) {

global $connection;

if(!$result) {

    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
}
```

then you can just simply do something like this to insert into db.

```
$product_image = escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $image_temp_location = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($image_temp_location, UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . DS . $product_image);

    $query = query("INSERT INTO products(product_image) VALUES( '{$product_image}')");
```

Comment: That's what i'm attempting to do. The number is meant to be the name and is sent to the database with the same id as the name

Comment: I dont understand the whole reason for changing the name to a number though, it's just making a mess of everything. 

you should just do something like this.

Comment: hmmm, true, because i have the id which i can reference when displaying it instead. Maybe i just overthought the process

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple way to add the image

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a go

Comment: Let me know how you get on.

Comment: It seems to work only half the time. It uploads the file, or it updates the database, dont know why
$folder = "../uploads/" . $file_name;
  if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$folder)){
   $query2 = "INSERT INTO `nocas_19164639_admin`.`gal` (`id`, `photo`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, '$file_name', '1')";
   $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
   if($r1){
    echo "Uploaded";
   }else{
    echo "Failed";
   }
  }else{
   exit("Error while uploading file...");
  }

Comment: The table you are inserting into, is "id" set to auto increment?

Comment: I just tried it again after about 10 mins, and it worked. My phpadmin is playing up now. Will have to sort that one out, but, it looks like its working now, will test a few more times just to make sure

Comment: When your id is auto increment you dont need it in your Insert query. I also noticed that in the fix i sent you i have a function set for the Mysqli query. The function i use is just a little helper function that i put at the top of my functions it looks like this..

function query($sql) {

 global $connection;

 return mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}

Comment: I like to have the A_I in the query purely on the grounds of that i can see exactly what is being sent in each query. Oh yeah, that would clean up the code a little, i might do that. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you like to see exactly what is being sent? The AI will always increment by 1 regardless of whether or not it's in the query. 
For example if you have 6 rows already in the table. the next insert will automatically increment the id to the next integer, 7.
Is it all working okay now?

Comment: Yeah, i know. I'm one of those people who has to see it written, otherwise, they dont realise its being sent, and if a problem occurs, everything being sent is in my face.